# Access table data in local PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL on my local machine and create the table in my own database.

Database properties looks like

```
Name: MyDB
Tablespace: pg_default
Default tablespace: pg_default
System database? No
```

And my table properties looks like

```
Name: mytable
Tablespace: pg_default
System table? No
```

But when I try to do

```
select * from mytable;
```

I am getting

```
ERROR: relation "mytable" does not exist
```

Create table statement

```
create table mytable (
  .....
);
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: IF you created your table with quotes you need to reference it also with double quotes

Comment: Please show the complete `create table` statement you have used to create the table

Comment: Do you use the command line?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It was simple create table statement.

Comment: @Mihai - Yes I gave sql statement. i didn't use GUI.

Comment: Try to end the statement with `;`

Comment: @Mihai - I was using `;`

Comment: If all the commands you say worked are actually working, you're either connected to the wrong database (e.g. to template1 rather than MyDB) or you created the database in a schema other than `public`.  EDIT: Or you're connecting as a different user and did not `GRANT`.

Comment: Make sure you're in the right database (type `\c` at the command line) and then check that the table is actually where you think it is with `\dt`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and clearly, if the create statements were including double quotes around the tables names, you have to use them too in your select statement to see the table (granted that you are the proper user with the proper privileges on tables). (and it's case sensitive even in Windows...)

Comment: Correct, that's documented behaviour: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS